# Is there anything that can be done to stop my insoles sliding?

Tags: walking, footwear, shoes

About 3/4 weeks ago I bought some Karrimor Traveller Supa Men's Walking Shoes and I've noticed that the insoles are starting to move around inside the the shoe. After a few hours of wearing them, the insoles have slipped back away from the front, leaving about an inch at the toes.
So far I've just been wearing them with light cotton socks, but tied quite tight.

Is there anything I can try to stop this? Should I try to glue them back down, or is there a better way to stop this?

I'd rather not have to try and return them, the store's a bit out of my way, and I got them on sale.

Comment: [Shoe goo works well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_Goo). Cost me £3 for two tubes on eBay.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use 2 sided foam tape and hardly notice them at all. The good thing is that it keeps the insoles put yet is pretty easy to remove when the insoles need changing. They leave some traces, but not enough to cause me to look for alternatives!
[image]

Comment: I've previously just used glue, but this seems to be a better solution!

Comment: The old maxim applies: If it moves, when it shouldn't, use some Duck Tape...

Comment: Needs changing? Aren't insoles supposed to be pulled out after every longer walk?

Comment: I have no clue @Janis, I just work here. It works for my purpose, and I don't have an alternative answer...