# A removeable solution for slipping insoles?

Tags: shoes, footwear

[Is there anything that can be done to stop my insoles sliding?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/is-there-anything-that-can-be-done-to-stop-my-insoles-sliding) has a pretty good answer for semi-permanent solving of insole slippage.

However, I switch my insoles between two pairs of shoes on a daily basis so two-sided tape isn't a very good solution.  Are there any suggestions for people who need to switch their insoles around?

Answer (score 4):

By far the simplest and most hygienic solution is to buy two sets. That way when you change shoes the other pair can breathe and dry out.

This should be the preferred option. It also means you don't need to worry about what kind of tape to use.

Comment: Not exactly the cheapest though. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use the removable sticky stuff that teachers use to hang stuff on walls.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this trick for your exact issue but I have used it for similar issues.

I would attach a small amount of velcro to the inside of each shoe and the bottom of the insole. You'll want to be careful with your placement so that it doesn't alter the feel of the insole, which I'm guessing is a big reason you are using them. It should not take much to simply keep the insole in place, maybe a small strip on the front, back, and sides.

If you use the same side of velcro on both shoes then you can take the insole out of one and put it into another in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Even the thinnest of velcros would add an uncomfortable thickness, and locking/unlocking velcro in the confines of a shoe would be a troublesome affair.